# What is the difference between case when and decode?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between case when and decode? How do I rank by rank with a piece of code I have

```
select customer.customerid,customer.contractid,customer.termed,customer.bracnchcode,  
(case    
when customer.contractid<5000000000 then 'A'   
when 5000000000<customer.contractid <=100000000000 then'B'    
else 'C'    
end) as rank   
from customer;
```

It happens 1 every thing I don't understand

Comment: You probably are doing *somthing else* as you are *thinking*. This is not a valid syntax `5000000000<customer.contractid <=100000000000`

Comment: `CASE` is *standard* SQL syntax and does everything that `DECODE()` does.  I recommend standard SQL over bespoke, database-specific functionality if the two are essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid; should be something like this:

```
SELECT customer.customerid,
       customer.contractid,
       customer.termed,
       customer.bracnchcode,
       (CASE
           WHEN customer.contractid < 5000000000
           THEN
              'A'
           WHEN customer.contractid BETWEEN 5000000001 AND 100000000000
           THEN
              'B'
           ELSE
              'C'
        END) AS RANK
  FROM customer;
```

As of your question regarding `DECODE`: it would make things way more complex in this case because you'd have to **calculate** the difference between `contractid` and boundaries you set check `sign` of the difference, probably use nested `decode`s which then becomes difficult to read and even worse to understand. Stick to `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

`DECODE` can be used if you classifies on the *equals condition*. E.g.

```
Customer_id  Rank
1            A
2            B
else         C
```

You'll write

```
 DECODE(customer_id,1,'A',2,'B','C')
```

If you classifies based on a *range* use `CASE  WHEN`

```
Customer_id        Rank
1   ..  499        A
500 .. 1000        B
else               C
```

This would be coded as

```
CASE WHEN Customer_id < 500  THEN 'A'
     WHEN Customer_id < 1000 THEN 'B'
     ELSE 'C' END as RANK
```

Note that the case is performed in sequential order of the `WHEN` parts and on the first *true* condition you quit, so in the *second* `WHEN` you do not need to exculde the lower bound (e.g. with `BETWEEN`) as this is *automaticaly* true because the first `WHEN`is *not true* if you get the the second one.